# Avoid showing UIAlertView when using PFLogInViewController

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, pfloginviewcontroller

I'm using a subclass of the `PFLogInViewController` in which I want to display errors in a different way to that of the default behaviour which is to pop up a `UIAlertView`.

Does anyone know if there's a way to avoid showing the `UIAlertView`? I'm already using the following method, however that doesn't actually allow me to avoid the `UIAlertView` being shown in the event of a failed login.

```
- (BOOL)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController shouldBeginLogInWithUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PFLogInViewController` does not provide hooks to change this behavior. You might want to build your own custom `PFLogInViewController` subclass and override the method which display alert view when login failed.

Since PFLogInViewController's code [has been open sourced](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS), according to it the method which displays an alert view is `_loginDidFailWithError`.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/blob/master/ParseUI/Classes/LogInViewController/PFLogInViewController.m#L382-L390

> ```
> - (void)_loginDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
>     if (_delegateExistingMethods.didFailToLogIn) {
>         [_delegate logInViewController:self didFailToLogInWithError:error];
>     }
>     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PFLogInFailureNotification object:self];
>
>     NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"Login Error", @"Login error alert title in PFLogInViewController");
>     [PFUIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle:title error:error];
> }
> ```

For example, if you like the following, you can not to display alerts when the login fails.
Define `MYLogInViewController` as subclass of `PFLogInViewController`

```
@interface MYLogInViewController : PFLogInViewController

@end

@implementation MYLogInViewController

- (void)_loginDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(logInViewController:didFailToLogInWithError:)]) {
        [self.delegate logInViewController:self didFailToLogInWithError:error];
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PFLogInFailureNotification object:self];
}

@end
```

and use it instead `PFLogInViewController`

```
MYLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[MYLogInViewController alloc] init];
logInViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```